# Sigmoid confidence curves in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons, sigmoid-curve

I have a logistic regression model that predicts the probability of an outcome based on one input variable. I am able to plot the curve just fine and show my group how the probability is predicted to change as our input variable changes.

How, mathematically (how to do it in software comes later), can I calculate confidence bounds for the entire curve? I am able to calculate confidence intervals for the probabilities at each input value and plot those (makes for a pretty graph), but this approach does have the claimed coverage (contain the true sigmoid curve 95% of the time when I calculate 95% confidence bounds). Further, there are clearly nonsense curves that fail to be rejected by doing a confidence interval at each input value; in particular, monotonicity is not required, yet that sigmoid curve most certainly is monotonic.

Further, still, there are issues with multiple comparisons when I do one confidence interval per predicted probability. Each confidence interval represents one opportunity for the prediction to escape the confidence bounds, and even one escaped prediction means that the predicted curve does not fall in the confidence region. Since the curve exists on a continuum, there are infinitely many comparisons, which makes me think that the correct approach is to say that the confidence interval is $[0,1]$, which is not super helpful a probability.

("Dave, put a confidence interval around the predicted curve," seems like a very simple request, and it has turned out to be challenging!)

Comment: See https://www.bookdepository.com/Simultaneous-Inference-Regression-Wei-Liu/9781138111684

The final chapter has application to logistic regression.